# Minimum javascript string value for use in backbone comparator

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I want a minimum string value to use in my comparator. Assume that my validation prevents name from being the empty string.

This appears to be working correctly. Are there any values of "name" for which it will fail?

```
S.FileList = Backbone.Collection.extend
  model: S.File                    
  comparator: (file) ->     
    # We add display files alphabetically, but with meta.file at the top. 
    if file.get("name") == "meta.file"
      return ""
    return file.get("name")
```

Comment: What if a name is empty?

Comment: @thejh: "Assume that my validation prevents name from being the empty string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your validation prevents `name` from being the empty string, and enforces it being a string: Yes, this will work. `"" < str` where `str` is any string other than `""`.

Again, you've got to make sure that `typeof name is 'string'`, because while

```
"" < "0"
```

is true,

```
"" < 0
```

is false.